# Why is Visual VM showing a thread as parked when it is getting scheduled?

Tags: scala, future, executioncontext

I have created a custom Execution Context (FixedThreadPool with 100 workers) in Scala to run IO Bound Futures. I am making db calls to Cassandra in these futures.

I have made the context available to the DB related Futures. In the log messages I see that these threads are getting executed in the specified thread pool.

[image]

However Visual VM tells a different story.

[image]

This shows that the threads have a CPU utilisation of 0%.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I you are using non blocking async driver than you will not see any CPU utilization at application level

Comment: Even though that async call gets executed from within a Future ? In that case the Future needs to be scheduled to get to the async execution part.